# Shareaholic registration

Tags: website

On the Shareaholic website there is a [login page](http://www.shareaholic.com/login). Are there any benefits to be a registered member? Are there features that I'm not even aware of without registration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you register, sites like Evernote, bit.ly, and other sites that require registration are already logged in because you're logged into Shareaholic. I find this to be a quick way of getting notes and emails sent out quickly.

Also, it remembers all your sites and if you use it on multiple computers or browsers, you'll be able to just login and the settings will be saved.